# IIS as reverse proxy

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, http-authentication

I'm looking into to having IIS doing authentication in an application being executed on a J2EE server (JBoss). Is there any ways to have IIS work as reverse proxy and propagating the username and/or roles of the user the proxied application (JBoss). And also what IIS version would I need, if it's possible?
I have license for IIS, so I'd like to do it in IIS, but otherwise I'd prefer open source.

Thanks!

Tomas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not open source, but ApplicationRequestRouting for IIS 7.0 can act as a reverse proxy.

More Info:
http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/09/application-request-routing-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy.aspx

Download:
http://www.iis.net/extensions/ApplicationRequestRouting

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft ISA server does that - you may want to look at that first.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for open source, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2):

[IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) does reverse proxy and URL rewriting for IIS5/6/7.

It's open source, and uses a syntax evry similar to mod_proxy / .htaccess for its rules.

You need v2.0 to get the reverse proxy capability.

Comment: IIRF doesn't work for me because of this issue: http://iirf.codeplex.com/workitem/32479

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at http://www.managedfusion.com/products/url-rewriter/